# avoid objXmlHttp json string escaped in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I have a classic asp page which retreives encoded token from web service, something like this:

```
objXmlHttp.Open "POST", "http://some_web_service", False
objXmlHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
objXmlHttp.Send something
If objXmlHttp.Status = 200 Then
    response.write ("objXmlHttp.ResponseText:"&objXmlHttp.ResponseText)
```

I see in my objXmlHttp.ResponseText slashes escaped like this

```
"...rVw1s\/Qn30..." (see "\" and "/" after "s").
```

When I send this token via query string (Response.Redirect) to an asp.net mvc controller of another web application I receive it with the backslash escaped too, like this

```
"...rVw1s\\/Qn30...", that breaks.
```

I'd like not to do replace, if is it possible, not in asp (sending token) and not in asp.net mvc (receiving token).

Is it possible to avoid to receive escaped slash in objXmlHttp in classic asp?

Or maybe I'm doing something wrong or missing something...

Comment: What is objXmlHttp an instance of?  (In your ASP.Net app if you examine the string in the debugger it will add the double escapes when it displays it but they are not actually in the string itself)

Comment: @AlexK. the page in which is used objXmlHttp is not ASP.Net, it's Classic ASP (ASP 3.0)

Comment: I mean if you send `aa\tbb` from anything to your asp.net mvc app, in the debugger you will see `aa\\tbb`

Comment: Ok, understood,you mean maybe it's correct having it, but how I can remove the backslash in receiving mvc controller? ...since the right token has only the forward slash... any decode in some way? or just replace it?

Comment: @Falco de-serialize it properly in MVC.

Comment: @Lankymart In my action method I receive a token in form of string, not a json serialized object...

Comment: @Falco if you are going to send JSON it should be serialised following the rules of serialised JSON then deserialised using either inbuilt .Net serialisation or Newtonsoft's JSON.Net. That way you avoid any decoding issues of a raw string.

Comment: @Lankymart - Yesss! thx worked this way: 1. in ASP sender doing Server.URLEncode of my token (without this not worked...) 2. Serialize the encoded token using aspJSON in a simple object (something in format like {"token":"myXYZtoken"}), sent serialized object to my MVC action method. 3. In MVC Action receiver method deserilized using Newtonsoft JsonConvert into dynamic object, 4.found into the object the "token" property in the right formatting way. I will post the solution as answer. many many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank @Lankymart for advice about Json wrapping the data to send:

worked this way:

1. in ASP sender doing Server.URLEncode of my token (without this not worked...)*
2. Serialize the encoded token using aspJSON in a simple object (something in format like {"token":"myXYZtoken"}), sent serialized object to my MVC action method.
3. In MVC Action receiver method deserilized using Newtonsoft JsonConvert into 
   dynamic object
4. found into the object the "token" property in the right formatted way.

*N.B: Only Server.URLEncode of the original token without wrapping in Json object did not worked.